# Replace a string with another string (could have any strange chars)

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I have a string, with newlines and odd characters in it, like quotes, commas, backslashes etc (it can be quite long, so not simple to escape characters).

Eg

```
STRING_FROM_BASH="blah2 => '/blah',"

perl -0777 -i.original -pe "s/###matchingchars/$STRING_FROM_BASH/igs" myfile
```

I get an error

```
Having no space between pattern and following word is deprecated at -e line 1
```

Which I assume is because its interpolating the bash string.

Is there any way to make Perl not interpolate that replacement string?

Comment: The discussion and answers on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed might be of use here. Assigning the string to a perl variable and then using that variable might also work better.

Comment: You could always just use the program arguments. But the fancier perl quoting methods can probably fairly safely quote an arbitrary string (though I don't know what those are offhand).

Comment: Can `###matchingchars` contain a newline? If not, I don't see why you used `-0777`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to generate Perl code from the shell.

You can pass it as a command-line argument:

```
perl -0777 -i.original -pe '$S //= pop; s/###matchingchars/$S/igs' myfile "$STRING_FROM_BASH"
```

You can pass it as an environment variable:

```
S="$STRING_FROM_BASH" perl -0777 -i.original -pe 's/###matchingchars/$ENV{S}/igs' myfile
```

Comment: Super, I had found another solution, but this works fine and feels a bit nicer, so will switch to this.

Comment: @Ian `%ENV` is actually better solution. :)

Comment: Ok, thanks, can I just ask, where I could read about the pop thing ?

Comment: @Ian without arguments it operates on `@ARGV` or `@_` inside subroutine. http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html

Comment: Placing the string first and using `shift` would make far more sense. It's tradition to place the opened ended list of files last.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Etan, I've found a workaround, I set the variable up, and then use it within Perl like the following...

```
replacement=STRING_FROM_BASH perl -0777 -i.original -pe 's/###matchingchars/$ENV{replacement}/igs' myfile
```